# NSDate zero out hour minuts and seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate

I have an NSDate which I want zero-out hour, minutes and seconds. The result I want is: `2014-02-19 00:00:00 +0000`. I have tried the following:

```
NSUInteger flags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents* components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flags fromDate:self.birthDatePicker.date];
NSDate* birthDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components];
```

For some reason I get this: `2014-02-19 23:00:00 +0000`. Hour isn't zeroed out. I have also tried to  set `[components setHour:0]`. But I get the same result `23` for hours. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: consider timezones... your local timezone is GMT+1 and when you log the date using NSLog it gives its time in GMT

Comment: Need of the time zone depends on the use case. If you hard code your time zone to the date you'll easily break it for the users on different time zones. What you need is a simple date formatter with a style or format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always helpful:

**WWDC Videos**

2011 `Session 117 - Performing Calendar Calculations`

2013 `Session 227 - Solutions to Common Date and Time Challenges`

This contains the information you probably want:

Session **227** @ **13m25s**, "Common Operations"  / "Calculate Midnight".

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this library: https://github.com/mysterioustrousers/MTDates

I had the similar problem I've decided to use it. It has a lot of date related functions. The one you need is:

```
- (NSDate *)mt_startOfCurrentDay;
```

About time zones. NSDate has independent from time zone format. Time zone you need you can specify in NSDateFormatter instance.

**Update** Full code example

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"%@", date); // 2014-02-20 11:11:40 +0000
[NSDate mt_setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
NSLog(@"%@", [[date mt_startOfCurrentDay] mt_stringFromDateWithISODateTime]); // 2014-02-20 00:00:00 +0000
```

For other date format, setup NSDateFormatter with time zone and your custom date format

**One more solution** This one without library:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"%@", date); // 2014-02-20 11:36:20 +0000
NSUInteger flags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSCalendar *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:currentCalendar.calendarIdentifier];
calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:flags fromDate:date];
date = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
NSLog(@"%@", date); // 2014-02-20 00:00:00 +0000
```

P.S. Btw I have GMT+3 time zone

Comment: Ouups … I have misread what you want, now I posted a right function for you

Comment: @Andres, I've updated my post, I hope, now it's all caveats from the question?

Answer (score 3):

Consider this category on NSDate:

```
@interface NSDate (Utilities)
- (NSDate *) dateAtStartOfDay;
@end

@implementation
- (NSDate *) dateAtStartOfDay
{

   NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSYearCalendarUnit| NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit |  NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit) fromDate:self];
   [components setHour:0];
   [components setMinute:0];
   [components setSecond:0];
   return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:components];
}
@end
```

Code taken from Erika Sadun [NSDate Extension](https://github.com/erica/NSDate-Extensions)

Comment: This is identical with the OP's way. His was a bit more clean.

Comment: Not identical... the OP way doesn't take into account hour, min, sec etc... and doesn't set them to zero.

Comment: Not using those unit flags is the exact same thing as setting them to zero. Run his code and yours to see for yourself.

Comment: You are totally right, the have the same time. The code of the OP and mine shows 23, cause of the localeTimeZone that has an offset of 3600s. Log an NSDate give you the time in absolute reference. To have a start date time in my coutry it needs to subtract (or add) the offset.